# django-cms makemigrations error: No module named 'packaging'

Tags: python, django, django-cms, modulenotfounderror, django-manage.py

I am starting out in django-cms and I am trying to install cms from the official cms documentation. I created my virtual environment and installed Django and django-cms.

The next steps are to create a project with django-admin, and adding the django-cms in the installed apps. The project is going great till now. But, when I try to migrate my installed apps in the database I get the error "No module named 'packaging'". I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Another tutorial tells me to startproject using 
`djangocms myproject`
but it doesn't work (it's probably outdated as I couldn't find any variations anywhere else)

My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'treebeard',
]

SITE_ID = 1

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
]
```

After this, I run the
`py manage.py makemigrations`
But I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\art\Graphic Design\Coding\law-&-stuff\myproject\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\art\Graphic Design\Coding\law-&-stuff\myproject\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\art\Graphic Design\Coding\law-&-stuff\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\art\Graphic Design\Coding\law-&-stuff\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "E:\art\Graphic Design\Coding\law-&-stuff\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "E:\art\Graphic Design\Coding\law-&-stuff\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "E:\art\Graphic Design\Coding\law-&-stuff\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\art\Graphic Design\Coding\law-&-stuff\venv\Lib\site-packages\cms\models\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .placeholdermodel import *  # nopyflakes
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\art\Graphic Design\Coding\law-&-stuff\venv\Lib\site-packages\cms\models\placeholdermodel.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cms.utils import get_language_from_request, get_site_id, permissions
  File "E:\art\Graphic Design\Coding\law-&-stuff\venv\Lib\site-packages\cms\utils\permissions.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cms.utils.compat.dj import available_attrs
  File "E:\art\Graphic Design\Coding\law-&-stuff\venv\Lib\site-packages\cms\utils\compat\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from packaging.version import Version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
```

I am following the documentation from https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/install.html. I think it might have something to do with how the packages have been installed? But, I don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: it looks for me that the path is not right. Try to explorer where the Version is located and specify path from "cms.utils...."

Comment: @Julik hi thanks for the help, I realised the module was not installed by default so I installed it and it works properly!

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution!

The packaging module was not installed by default, I upgraded my pip with `py -m pip install --upgrade pip` and installed the module with `py -m pip install packaging` and it works now.